# How to insert a diagonal arrow through a word and write text corresponding to the arrow?

Tags: packages

I'm wondering if it is possible to replicate the following in TEX:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `cancel` package and `amsmath` for `\text` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,cancel}
\begin{document}
  \[\cancelto{0, \text{material is conservative}}{\text{consumption}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I use this in the math environment align, if I have \begin{align*}   \end{align*} ?

Comment: I got it :) \cancelto{0, \text{S.S}}{\text{Accumulation}}

Comment: Perhaps better `0\text{, material is conservative}` so the space between the comma and "material" is the standard text space for the comma?

Answer (score 2):

*Variant:* if you want to use it outside a math environment, you can use `\ensuremath` and `text`. By default the text at the end of the diagonal arrow will be in scriptsize, but you can change that with `\displaystyle`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, cancel} 

\begin{document}

\ensuremath{\cancelto{0, \text{material is conservative}}{\text{Consumption}}}
\vskip 1cm

\ensuremath{\cancelto{\displaystyle 0, \text{material is conservative}}{\text{Consumption}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]